# Calculating the length of two shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, intersection, splitting, length

I created the yellow area as a shapefile by hand. Then I calculated the perimeter. I also created another shapefile (blue) manually and calculated the length, see image 1.

The next step was to subtract the perimeter of the yellow area with the length of the blue line and add the remaining green length (total green length - blue line) to calculate the length of the purple line, which was created manually, see image 2.

Does anyone know if there is another way to calculate the purple length? I tried using `Vector > Intersection` to automatically generate the yellow area. Unfortunately, this did not work (the layer was empty). After that, I used `Vector > Union`. But I have no access to the yellow area, see image 3.

I am at a loss at the moment.

[image]

I discarded the approach with Union and Intersection and instead applied split the line for both shapefiles. Then examined the attribute tables and created a query using a Virtual Layer.

`SplitContourLine` returns five values where only one is relevant (row 1), see image 4.

I solved the problem by taking out all 0 and greater 5000 values, see image 5.

Now I want to access this inner line without using this condition `c.ContourLen < 5000` to be more flexible when using this method for other examples.

[image]

Comment: Sharing your data could improve chances to get an answer. Otherwise, one first has to create own test-data.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vnl0wxcw4zhdegn/AAAhvgEq6NbIfjc7ro87jIOza?dl=0 I am currently using "split with lines". See SplitLine and SplitContourLine. Now I am experimenting how to calculate the purple line based on the partial information

Comment: If you already have the splitted lines, you can simply delete the segments you don't need, calculate the length of the remaining ones and add them. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Select the purple line manually, than calculate the length with field calculator, just for the selected segment.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand the problem: why can't you select the segment manually and calculate it's length? Maybe I overlook something?

Comment: @Babel My fault, I hope it is better explained now

Comment: OK, still confused, sorry. So what you want to do is **not** measuring the length (this should be easy, even without virtual layers, simply using field calculator, as stated above), but you want to access the segment of the contour that is between the two points?

Comment: I have already calculated the result of the total length using the field calculator. Works great.

The problem I have at the moment is that the red line was divided into segments and I need only a certain part for the calculations. If I manually check and clean up the attribute table with a SQL query everything works. Only I would like to solve this step also no longer manually and there the question arises how to solve this :)

Comment: You could check which segment of the `SplitContourLine` touches the line `DistanceLineBerghotelOsnabrueck` twice: this is the segment you're interested in. However, your layers are in EPSG:4326, so distance measurements will not make any sense as units are in degrees.

Comment: @Babel The measurements at project properties are set for ellipsoid WGS 84 EPSG:7030. The unit for the distance measurements are in meters. Hope, that fits so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one line layer for the contour and one straight line called `'distance'`, split the contour layer with the `'distance'` line. Then you have a new `'contour_split'` layer with three segments: one between the intersecting points and each before and after the points.

Then create line intersection points that create a layer called `'points'`. Now the segment you're interested in is the one that touches both points (the other two segments will touch only one of the points).

To achieve this, use ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) on the `'contour_split'` layer with this expression - the [`overlay_touches()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#overlay-touches) function is available since QGIS 3.16:

```
array_length(overlay_touches('points', $id, limit:=2)) = 2
```

*Screenshot: the black contour line (divided into three segments based on the crossing points) is crossed by the red `'distance'` line. Select by expression returns the segment you're interested in (highlighted in yellow):*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want is length calculation of connected line. My answer would be to use network anlysis toolbox. Now it is really strong in QGIS and it will do both : calculate the length + create a line feature.

1. Get all your geometry part in one layer.
2. For segment that are crossing each other connect vertices to make the layer "routable" (use magnet or
3. Use shortest path point to point algorithm. Use your routable layer (or even a selection of your routable layer) and define start and end point. Let the other option blank and execute.

It would work for your example and could be adaptable for projects like that. You can select only some features to be used for network, it will force the route calculation to go the way you want.